# Rails Routing Constraint - Limit paths to development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, constraints

I am trying to add a constraints to our error-routes so that requests to certain routes would not get redirected to a 404-page if we're working on our app in `development`.

```
match '*unmatched_route', :to => 'application#handle_404', via: :all, constraints: lambda { |request| !request.url["/rails/info"]  }
```

This is the rule we currently have in place. All "invalid" routes being redirected to a 404-page. Now I want to upgrade this to only allow access to `/rails/info/*` if the app is in development-mode.

I tried the following:

```
match '*unmatched_route', :to => 'application#handle_404', via: :all, constraints: lambda { |request| !request.url["/rails/info"] && !Rails.env.development? }
```

I am not sure where exactly the problem is. The addition inside the constraint does not seem to have any effect, thus I believe I am using the constraint entirely wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Might not be as elegant, but you could put the route inside a `unless` block, like this:

```
unless Rails.env.development?
  match '*unmatched_route', :to => 'application#handle_404', via: :all, constraints: lambda { |request| !request.url["/rails/info"]  }
end
```

Comment: This answer has been given and deleted before. I basically only want to allow access to `rails/info/*` if the request matches said URL AND it's in development. Otherwise I want the user to get redirected to 404, no matter if staging, production or development.